# Predicted line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict

I have fitted the following model with lmer:

```
mod1<-lmer(logpd~arm*lspline(pday,knots=2)+(1|pid),data=q1)
```

I would like to recreate the following plot with ggplot:

```
obsmeans<-aggregate(q1$logpd,by=data.frame(q1$pday,q1$arm),mean);obsmeans
fitted<-aggregate(fitted(mod1),by=data.frame(q1$pday,q1$arm),mean);fitted

plot(obsmeans$x~fitted$q1.pday)
lines(fitted$x[which(fitted$q1.arm=="SP")]~fitted$q1.pday[which(fitted$q1.arm=="SP")],lty=1)
lines(fitted$x[which(fitted$q1.arm=="SP/ART")]~fitted$q1.pday[which(fitted$q1.arm=="SP/ART")],lty=2)
```

[image: predicted lines]

I am able to plot the observed means and fitted means with ggplot but do not know how would add the predicted lines?

```
pred<-data.frame(obsmeans,fitted)
ggplot(pred,aes(x=x,y=q1.pday))+
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot]

EDIT

here are the observed means and fitted values:

```
obsmeans
   q1.pday q1.arm      x
1        0     SP 3.5566
2        1     SP 2.7925
3        2     SP 0.7763
4        3     SP 0.5454
5        7     SP 0.0973
6        0 SP/ART 3.4309
7        1 SP/ART 0.9286
8        2 SP/ART 0.1898
9        3 SP/ART 0.0482
10       7 SP/ART 0.0000

fitted:
  q1.pday q1.arm       x
1        0     SP  3.7687
2        1     SP  2.3389
3        2     SP  0.8795
4        3     SP  0.7068
5        7     SP  0.0641
6        0 SP/ART  3.1345
7        1 SP/ART  1.5416
8        2 SP/ART -0.0562
9        3 SP/ART -0.0345
10       7 SP/ART  0.0172
```

Comment: See the `sjplot` package...   https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_marginal_effects.html

Comment: Could you please post a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the data frames for the observed means and fitted values. Is that sufficient?